# zlib: Differences Between the `deflate` and `compress` Functions

Tags: compression, zlib, deflate

What are the differences between the `deflate()` and `compress()` functions in zlib?

I have looked through online examples and some used deflate while others used compress.

How should I decide which situation I would use one over the other?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

`compress()` is used to compress the data in a single call, and always compresses to the *zlib* format, which is deflate data with a two-byte header and a four-byte check value trailer.  `compress()` is used by itself.

`deflate()` is used to compress data a chunk at a time, and/or to compress to other formats such as *gzip*-wrapped or *raw*, and with other options, such as memory levels and compression strategies.

You would use `compress()` if you have all the data available at once and enough memory to hold the result, and you want the default compression format, memory usage, and strategy.  Otherwise, you would use `deflate()`.

deflate() is not used by itself.  You need to use `deflateInit()` or `deflateInit2()` to initialize the `z_stream` structure used by `deflate()`.  Then you call `deflate()` one or more times to take in data to compress and to make available the result.  At the end, `deflateEnd()` is called to free the memory resources used in the structure.  You can read the documentation in *zlib.h* and at http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html for more information.

Comment: Mark Adler is [definitely the authority on this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Adler).

Comment: thank you.  i read some of it but didn't quite understand it at first. It was just too much information, but i've gone and reread it.

Comment: great...now i know why it is called adler-32

Comment: @MarkAdler Very detailed answer. any good source/book to read more about Zlib or Gzip?